# zsh: command not found (some modules)

Tags: bash, zsh

I used bash and installed different packages. But when i install zsh, some modules are missing, for example (angular cli, nvm - node version manager), but detected npm and node js.
Why is this happening?[image]

Comment: Is there some node-releated code in .bashrc which needs to be migrated to .zshrc?

Comment: @nohillside I cant find .bashrc in $HOME directory, but found file .zshrc. What do I need to do for that?

Comment: Please show text as text not images so that we can read it.

Comment: How did you make nvm, mpm, node etc work on bash?

Comment: Well, when you installed nvm etc, something got added to your bash profile which is now missing in the zsh profile. If you can't find it, you could also try to reinstall these tools.

Comment: @nohillside ok, thanks. But its strange, that my Webstorm IDE uses zsh finds Angular CLI module. :/

Comment: Well, you could run `bash -l -c type nvm` to see where `nvm` is stored, and then add that directory to your PATH in zsh.

Comment: Can you post the output of the command @nohillside mentioned? How did you install these tools (homebrew or otherwise)?

Comment: You need to run it in your system to get the relevant output. I don‘t use node.

Comment: Why is this tagged bash and zsh? You need to clarify which shell you are using. BTW, are you sure that you really talk about `modules` in the sense of **zsh-modules** (see _man zshmodules_)?